# On the complexity of finding a minimal linear extension

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory

I have a finite set $P$ of $n$ elements and a topological ordering $R_c$ over $P$, where the transitive closure of $R_c$ is a partial order $R$ of $P$. Finding a linear extension is easy and enumerating them is #P-complete. However, what is the complexity of finding a set of relations $R_c^*$ such that the transitive closure of $R_c^*$ is a linear extension $R^*$ of $R$ and $|R_c^* \setminus R_c |$ is minimal? Let $t(X)$ be the transitive closure of a set of relations $X$, then what we are looking for is

$$ R_c^*\supseteq R_c\; \text{s.t. } \; \not\exists R_c' \; \text{where}\; t(R_c') \;\;\text{is a linear extension of} \;\; t(R_c) \;\;\text{and}\;\; |R_c'| < |R_c^*|$$

Comment: After further search this problem looks like a duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/106753/minimum-number-of-edges-added-to-a-dag-to-get-unique-topological-order